# How to sort a list of dates in a text file

Tags: linux, date, sort

Let's assume I have a text file with a list of dates (dd.mm.yyyy).

```
01.01.2020
01.03.2020
01.01.2019
```

How do I sort them out? (oldest to newest in a "from top to bottom" fashion)?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question with things such as what you've tried?

Comment: Similar: [how to sort file by DD-MM-YYYY dates](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/485705), [Sort lines according to date and time](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/487823) (and probably many other)

Comment: I think temporarily setting your locale to C should work as well. I.e:  `LC_ALL=C sort -r infile`

Comment: @ValentinBajrami That would still sort on the days, month and years (in that order of precedence), not year, month, day, which would be needed to get them in the correct time order.

Comment: @Kusalananda could you please point to an example or documentation that it wouldn't work as expected? Just curious though

Comment: @ValentinBajrami I ran your command, it sorts `01.03.2020` first and `01.01.2019` last.  If there had been an `31.12.2019` entry, that would have been first even though `01.01.2019` is earlier.  It does not work as it sorts on the day first, not the year.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah that's true. Haven't thought of such an edge case. I should have tested it better myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sort -t. -k 3,3 -k 2,2 -k 1,1 <filename
```

Sets the delimiter to be "." and then sorts by key 3 (yyyy), 2 (mm), 1 (dd)

Comment: You may want to add `-n` or change `-k3,3` to `-k3,3.4` in case there is more text in the input after the date.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F . '{ print $3, $2, $1 }' file | sort | awk -v OFS=. '{ print $3, $2, $1 }'
01.01.2019
01.01.2020
01.03.2020
```

This reverses the fields with a tiny `awk` script into a YYYY MM DD order.  This can be sorted with plain `sort` into the correct date order.  The last `awk` puts the data back the way it was, with a dot as the delimiter.